# geting xml code from google routing api in android studio

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to run google routing api. It is basically a link where you add origin and destination and that produces XML code.

The problem I am having is that i can't figure out how to get the XML code that the link produces to the XML file in Android Studio for example going to the following link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA

will produce routing xml code from Chicago to Los Angeles

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find everything you need [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) after "connect and download data".

Basically make a `HttpUrlConnection`, open it, and you'll get your inputStream by calling `connection.getInputStream()`. Then, for example the DOM XML parser can use a simple inputstream like so:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
Element xmlElement = db.parse(in).getDocumentElement();
in.close();
```

Or check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) for more information.

Comment: im getting an error now for newDocumentBuilder() it says unhandelled exception but i have bade a try catth for it